# Trying to create a batch file to map Sharepoint as a network drive

Tags: sharepoint

We have Sharepoint mapped as a network drive and now I am trying to create a batch file that will remap it if and when it disconnects.

This is what I have but I get an error saying

> Network path cannot be found

```
@echo Create new S: drive mapping

@net use S: \\https://XXXXXemail.sharepoint.com/sites/CallCenter/Shared Documents /persistent:yes

@echo Create new S: drive mapping

@net use S: \\https://XXXXXemail.sharepoint.com/sites/CallCenter/Shared Documents /persistent:yes

:exit

@pause
```

Could someone share some pointers? I'm pretty much a novice in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `net use` is not correct.

- Url should be in quotes because it contains space
- All slashes should be changed to backslash
- @SSL should be added after the domain

Example:

```
net use S: "\\XXXXXemail.sharepoint.com@SSL\sites\CallCenter\Shared Documents" /persistent:yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting to note that when issuing the net use command from the command prompt, successfully, the link that is registered in the file explorer looks different.

I see a "@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites" inserted after the .com

Anyway, if you can mount from a command line, the  path to use in a batch file may be found in the file explorer.

Regards

Hallvard the horrible